# How do I determine how many subscribers my extension has?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a number of Chrome extensions that support subscriptions in-app-payments: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

I used to beable to go to the Google Payments Centre (https://payments.google.com/payments) and easily work out how many subscribers my extension has but Google recently updated that page so I cant work out how many paying subscribers my extension now has.

I have tried to contact Google about this but they sent me around in circles between different support teams twice before sending me here.

Does anyone know if there is a way API or otherwise that I can find out how many paying subscribers my Chrome Extension has?